# "Add another item" fails after 40 fields in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I have a form with "image" field where unlimited image fields can be added by clicking on "add another item" button. After 40 image fields, I get an ajax error "An error occurred while attempting to process /system/ajax: ajax.form.ajaxSubmit is not a function". Ajax call is failing and returning some JS files in response which is wierd. Appreciate your thoughts and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work around that I could figure out is to remove the ajax calls and do with usual POST method where the form refreshes by clicking on "add another item". Drupal is smart enough to remember all the rest of the values that the user filled in the form.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to the number of input variables you are posting across to the Ajax call. Check the value you have for 'max_input_vars' in your php.ini, and try increasing it.